# How to run ESP (Extensible Service Proxy) on localhost to simulate authentication locally?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-flexible

When I deploy Endpoints on the flexible environment, an nginx-based proxy (which is called Extensible Service Proxy) is deployed automatically as a container within the instance which is used for logging and authentication for the most part.

How to run ESP locally on local dev server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### STEPS:

1. I used docker for Windows https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/
2. I created a folder at root path of drive C (`C:/esp`), then I copied `serviceaccount.json` to it. `serviceaccount.json` holds the private key of a service account with the following roles:

   - Project -> Viewer
   - Cloud Trace -> Cloud Trace Agent
   - Service Management -> Service Controller

<sub>**ps: you would need to scroll down the menu to find the second and third roles :)**</sub>

<strike>3. Closed Kaspersky, otherwise `--volume C:/esp:/esp` won't work.</strike>

3. If you have Kaspersky 2017, go to Settings -> Protection -> Firewall -> Networks, then right-click on Docker NIC and select "Edit", and finally change from "public Network" to "Trusted Network".
4. Enabled C Drive sharing via Docker settings GUI.
5. Executed the command:

   > docker run --detach --name="esp" --publish 8082:8082 --volume C:/esp:/esp b.gcr.io/endpoints/endpoints-runtime:1 --service ****-backend-api.****-test.appspot.com --version 2016-12-06r1 --backend 10.0.75.1:8080 --service_account_key /esp/serviceaccount.json --http_port 8082

where `10.0.75.1` is IP of docker NIC, and `8080` is which backend local server is listening to.